# Call function with array of parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Is there a way of doing this without altering the function?

```
function foo(bar1, bar2, bar3)
{
    return bar1 + bar2 + bar3;
}
var array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(foo(array)); //6
```

Comment: `foo(array[0], array[1], array[2]);`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
console.log(foo.apply(null, array));
```

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to set the `this` value to the function itself. Although it doesn't make any difference, I'd say setting it to e.g. `null` is more semantical.

Comment: @pimvdb In function this usually points to window (in browser obviously), so I guess calling `foo.apply(window, array)` should be the natural choice.

Comment: @Lolo That makes sense :) I changed it again.

Comment: @Lolo: If you pass `null` as the `this` value then it will be set to the `window` automatically. But since the `this` value doesn't matter `null` would be more meaningful - but after all it doesn't matter at all.